# isIdleTimerDisabled not working in iOS 12

Tags: ios, ipad, ios12

Prior to iOS 12 using `isIdleTimerDisabled` has stopped our app from going to sleep, but ever since iOS 12 this no longer seems to work.

Is this a bug with iOS 12 or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems to me that if this was a wider issue, there would be more complaints about it with Apple.  Have you tried looking up any issues with the latest release?  Maybe apply a bug report with them

Comment: Yes and I couldn't find anything. However the issue seemed to be resolved when you toggle the "Screen Time" app on and off. So I suspect its an Apple issue.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean with "Screen Time" app? If I disable/activate the Screentime in Apple Settings App, it does not help.

Comment: @theguy That is what I was referring to. It didn't work when I first tried it but after leaving it for a while then toggling the setting on and off a few times it seemed to work correctly. I'm not 100% sure if that's the solution but thats the only thing I did and it started working again.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for clarifying. I have 2 devices which have this error and 4 don't. On one I can work around with the setting "Display" - Lock Device - "never" (which is okay for me). On the second, nothing helps (I will reinstall iOS).

Comment: Is there a solution to this issue? I have a video call app, and I need the device to disable auto-dimming of the screen during the video calls. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

This is for sure a bug and apparently Apple fixed it is `iOS 12.1.1`. You will see a new option under the `Guided Access` called `Mirror Display Auto-Lock`. Turn this on. Then go to `Settings` -> `Display and Brightness` -> `Auto-Lock` -> `Never`. This should fix it.

Here is a [link to the most active thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8565372) about this issue on the Apple Forums.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I have been suffering for the last 2 weeks trying to find a workaround for this issue.